# Parse an Escaped HTML that comes from Meteor Collecction

Tags: meteor

My collection contains escape HTML entities such as &lt, &gt etc. when i retrieve and display it, it escapes and prints the respective characters but does not interpret the HTML.

Eg:

`Template.Help.helpers({
     faq_content: function () {
        var x = Help.findOne({});
        return x.faq;
     }
  })`

assuming x takes the following value:

`x = 
   {
       faq:      &lt;div class=\"help_articles\"&gt;\\n
                 ....some_content....\\n
                 &lt;/div&gt;
       tips:     &lt;div class=\"help_articles\"&gt;\\n
                 ....some_content....\\n
                 &lt;/div&gt;
       articles: &lt;div class=\"help_articles\"&gt;\\n
                 ....some_content....\\n
                 &lt;/div&gt;
    }`

Even when i place this helper using three curly braces i.e,

`{{{faq_content}}}` ,

The content that gets displayed on the Browser is

`<div class="help_articles">....some_content....</div>`.

This gets displayed as text but i want it to be interpreted into HTML.
Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to _.unescape() the string once before presenting inside the {{{}}} braces:

```
Template.Help.helpers({
 faq_content: function () {
    var x = Help.findOne({});
    return _.unescape(x.faq);
 }
})
```

Be careful that the FAQ content is fully controlled by you and not submitted by your users without cleansing the content.

Comment: Great! Then go ahead and accept the answer so it isn't left unresolved @SyedIsSaqlain